# How to build a recipe but not include it in the OS image

Tags: yocto

I have custom recipes in my project which I include in the build process using IMAGE_INSTALL_append. This builds & adds all the recipes to the image.
What I need is that only certain recipes get added to the image and others are just built but not added to the image, so That I can install these manually using the rpms.
Is there a way to do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

you can build every package independently using bitbake without including it in the final image:

```
bitbake <recipe name>
```

This will build the recipe and put the rpm in the build/deploy/rpm directory.

Comment: Actually, that is something I am trying to avoid. Not building the recipe manually.  I was hoping to find a yocto directive that will allow me to build the recipe as a part of the project but just not include it in the image. From your response it appears that there is no option but to build the recipe manually. Thank you

Comment: You probably could hack something together: 

Create a recipe for a dummy image (like a dev-version) including the recipe you want to build. Secondly create yet another dummy recipe for building both, your so to say "release" image and the dummy image which in turn will build your recipe.

Comment: Thank You. I will try that out